# How to combine between the script and the action in the button

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have a button which I add in it a JQuery Script.

This button has as purpose to save some values in a list.

The problem that the button works perfectly but when i add the Script, the situation change and the button didn't works and became static (dead).

This is the code in the view :

```
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"   />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            $('#poste option:selected').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

and this is the code of methode save in the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(FlowViewModel model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + model.Nbr_Passage);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Gamme G = new Gamme();
                G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
                G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;
                //G.Last_Posts = model.PostePrecedentSelected;
                G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
                G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
                G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);

                ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]).Add(G);
                var list = ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]);


            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                   }
```

Comment: You're returning false from the handler, that means your button won't submit the form.

Comment: Thx, without the false, the utility of the script disappears. Infact, when i delete it, the page reload itself and the item of dropdownlist will not removed (which is the purpose of the function as you see).

Comment: If you want server side code to run when you do this sort of thing, you need AJAX, not submitting a form

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am beginner , I don't know what should i use, i am just asked a question last about how to remove an item from dropdownlist in the click of the button and they give me that script.
But when i am used, i find that the button is no more subbmit. So if  they are others solutions like using AJAX please just help me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove `return false;` from your script:

```
$(function () {
           $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                   $('#poste option:selected').remove();
           });
});
```

Comment: Thx, without the false, the utility of the script disappears. Infact, when i delete it, the page reload itself and the item of dropdownlist will not removed (which is the purpose of the function as you see).